# How to pick values from array and return instead of case in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query where I am using Case to replace the column name.

```
SELECT *,
  (CASE
      WHEN cp.client_type = 1 THEN 'AB'
      WHEN cp.client_type = 2 THEN 'BX'
      WHEN cp.client_type = 3 THEN 'PC'
      WHEN cp.client_type = 4 THEN 'DD'
      WHEN cp.client_type = 5 THEN 'DE'
  END) AS client_type 
  FROM clients as cp
```

The problem is Have 20 such cases and I do not want to use 20 when conditions in the query.

Is there a way I can use something like

```
SELECT *,
choose_from(Array("AB","BX","PC","DD","DE"), cp.client_type) as client_type from 
clients as cp
```

Comment: Are your types sequential? Are your codes always two letters?

Comment: yes types are sequential and can be matched with keys

Comment: *can be matched with keys* meaning?.

Comment: I mean the keys (indexes) of array, 1=> "AB", 2=>"BX"

Answer (score 3):

The right solution is to have a `clientTypes` table and use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT cp.*, cp.client_type_name
FROM clients cp LEFT JOIN
     client_types ct
     ON cp.client_type = ct.client_type;
```

If you don't have one, create one!

```
create table client_types (
    client_type_id int primary key,
    client_type_name varchar(255)
);

insert into client_types (client_type_id, client_type_name)
    values (1, 'AB'), (2, 'BX'), . . . ;
```

If you have an aversion to this for some reason, you can use the `elt()` function:

```
SELECT cp.*,
       ELT(client_type, 'AB', 'BX', 'PC', 'DD', 'DE') as client_type 
FROM clients cp;
```

I strongly caution against this, though, because a small typo could really mess up the values that you get -- and be hard to debug.

Comment: I think there is no client_type table!

Comment: Yes, and the point Gordon is  making is that there *should* be